# Drag and drop not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am using html to drag an image with `id ="drag1"` to drag and drop it to division with `id="div1"` and it doesn't work. I already have a division with 4 images and its source code is changing and it's working. Can you please help me fix this problem?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}


setTimeout(fun,15000);
function fun(){ document.getElementById("image1").src="bed1.jpg"
}

setTimeout(fun1,30000);
function fun1(){ document.getElementById("image2").src="bed1.jpg";
}

setTimeout(fun2,6000);
function fun2(){ document.getElementById("image3").src="bed1.jpg";
}

setTimeout(fun3,60000);
function fun3(){ document.getElementById("image4").src="bed1.jpg";
}

setTimeout(fun4,45000);
function fun4(){ document.getElementById("image5").src="bed1.jpg";
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background-color:white;
}
body {
background: lavender;
}
img {
height: 250px;
width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag Image</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:70px; color:firebrick;font-family:arial; font-size:50px">Medical Care</h1><br />
<img src="gethelp.png" height=100px width=130px style="margin-left:130px;" />

<div style="background-color:white;margin-top:140px;padding:50px;">
<img id="image1" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image2" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image3" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image4" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image5" src="bed.jpg">
</div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="bed.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Just help me figure out why drag and drop is not working with this code. It is working separately but not in this code.

Comment: Your HTML is awful. You really should try to write valid HTML that doesn't look like it was written 15 years ago.

Comment: on top of this the code is not valid. You may **not** put your HTML Elements inside the `<head></head>` tag!

Comment: I had edited the code. If it gets approved, you'll find that there is no problem in your code.

Comment: Please see your code.

Comment: thanks @Keshav It helped a lot!!

Comment: I am glad to help you.